# Am I using interact.js v1.1.3 incorrectly?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get http://interactjs.io/ working but nothing appears to happen even with this most simple setup:

```
interact('#thing').draggable({
    onstart:function(){
        console.dir('drag start');
    },    
    onmove:function(){
        console.dir('moving');
    },    
    onend:function(){
        console.dir('drag end');
    },
});
```

The events fire but the element doesn't move around.  Does the element need to be contained by anything special or have any kind of class or other attribute values?  Does the library have any dependencies that the documentation doesn't mention?

http://jsfiddle.net/vd2m9vxg/2/

In this fiddle, I should be able to move the red square around but nothing happens.  Does it work for you?  Maybe it's something with my browser. I've tested it in the latest versions of IE, FF and Chrome.

Comment: If you're going to down vote my question, at least leave a comment so I know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

interact.js doesn't move elements for you. It only provides the drag data. As shown in the [dragging demo](http://interactjs.io#dragging) on the project's homepage, moving the html element has to be done in a dragmove event handler:

```
// target elements with the "draggable" class
interact('.draggable')
  .draggable({
    // call this function on every dragmove event
    onmove: function (event) {
      var target = event.target,
          // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
          x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
          y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

      // translate the element
      target.style.webkitTransform =
      target.style.transform =
        'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

      // update the posiion attributes
      target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
      target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
    }
  });
```